# C++ Graph_lib and using "new"

Tags: c++

Consider I have to use the `Rectangle;` this way `Graph_lib::Rectangle;`. And there is a code that the below snip code has been used there:

```
rect.push_back(new Rectangle(Point(50,60),Point(80,90))); // add unnamed
```

The problem refers to the `new`. How can I use the `new` with `Graph_lib::Rectangle;` to gives me the above snip code?
PS: If I use `Rectangle;` without `Graph_lib::`, I get the *'Rectangle' : ambiguous symbol* error.

Comment: you mean... rect.push_back(new Graph_lib::Rectangle(Point(50,60), Point(80,90)));  ??

Comment: OW, it works!! Thanks, the problem is solved now.